# Is there a way to make Dialyzer watch code changes?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, dialyzer

I'm using [dialyxir](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir) which appends a `dialyzer` task to Mix. But it doesn't seem to have any `--watch` option that would rerun the type checking on file changes.

Is there a CLI way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you expect the static code analysis tool to be *watching* the filesystem? There is an explicit tool for that, named [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).

You might execute whatever you want, including `mix dialyzer` as shown in [usage](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch#usage) section.

Comment: I want that maybe because I come from the JS world where it's common to run a FS watcher running the unit tests / linter / type checking while we develop. It is more efficient than using an IDE with heavy plugins doing the same job. I will use fswatch then, it seems like a perfect fit.

Comment: Eh. [`node-watch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch) and all other watchers are wrappers for `fswatch` FWIW.

Comment: Could you share a full command you use with fswatch and mix dialyzer?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same as the accepted answer but with more detail:

```
fswatch -o lib | xargs -n1 -I{} mix dialyzer
```